# How to store float value in uint64_t variable in C?

Tags: c, casting, floating-point

I have an array of `uint64_t` values `uint64_t *data;` in where I need to store 4 different data types: `int`,`char*`, `bool`, `float`. I solved every type by simple casting to `(uint64_t)`, but it doesn`t work for float:

```
float val = 1.5f;
uint64_t var = (uint64_t) val;
printf("%.1f", (float) var); // prints 1.0
```

Is there a way to move data between variables on even lower level than casts? I've tried to combine casts in every way but the result was `0.0` or `1.0`.

Comment: You could try casting it to pointers, that way you won't affect the underlying value. i.e. `uint64_t *var = (uint64_t *) &val;`

Comment: *where I need to store 4 different data types* Why do you "need" to do this?  This screams "Bad design begging to invoke undefined behavior".  Use a proper `union`, or a large-enough `char` array and `memcpy()`.

Comment: @Jeeter And *that* is exactly the undefined behavior I just mentioned...

Comment: First of all: Integers and floating point values are encoded completely different in memory. With casting like `(uint64_t) val` you do a *conversion* from the `float` value to an `uint64_t` value. Which *truncates* the decimals and only leave the integer part. It's not a *bitwise* copy. Similar with the cast back to float, it's not any kind of bitwise copying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... to store `float` value in `uint64_t` variable ...

Copy it.

```
float var_f = 1.5f;
uint64_t var_u64;
_Static_assert(sizeof var_f <= sizeof var_u64, "Wide float");
memcpy(&var_u64, &var_f, sizeof var_f);
```

To recover

```
memcpy(&var_f, &var_u64, sizeof var_f);
printf("%g\n", var_f);
```

Comment: It might be good to know that on most systems (and definitely all current PC-like systems) `float` is a single-precision *32* bit type. Using `memcpy` like this will work, but it will leave half of the `uint64_t` variable in an indeterminate state (and exactly which half depends on the endianness of the system).